# Render SVG based on passed property "element"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

`element` will be either "listing_small", "listing_medium" or "listing_large". Now my goal was if `element` is e.g. listing_small my component will render the imported SVG `listing_small`. However, that didn't work out as expected.

```
import React from "react";
import listing_small from "assets/elements/listing_small.svg";
import listing_medium from "assets/elements/listing_medium.svg";
import listing_large from "assets/elements/listing_large.svg";
import { getElementName } from "utils/enums";

const ElementPreview = ({ element }) => {
  return <img src={element} alt={getElementName(element)} />;
};

export default ElementPreview;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an object that contains the svg src as values and the `listing_*` as keys.

Leaving it like:

```
const ELEMENTS = {
  listing_small, // its the same as listing_small: listing_small
  listing_medium,
  listing_large
}

const ElementPreview = ({ element }) => {
  return <img src={ELEMENTS[element]} alt={getElementName(element)} />;
};
```

Comment: Thank you! That looks great.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are receiving `element` as a string. So when it's passed to `src` attribute of `img` element it'll be like `src={"listing_small"}` or `src={"listing_medium"}` etc, which is not a valid image source path. That's the reason why the image element is not being rendered properly.

Below is one of the ways you can achieve this.

```
import React from "react";
import listing_small from "assets/elements/listing_small.svg";
import listing_medium from "assets/elements/listing_medium.svg";
import listing_large from "assets/elements/listing_large.svg";
import { getElementName } from "utils/enums";

const ElementPreview = ({ element }) => {
  let src = listing_small;
  if(element === "listing_medium") {
     src = listing_medium;
  } else if(element === "listing_large") {
     src = listing_large;
  }
  return <img src={src} alt={getElementName(element)} />;
};

export default ElementPreview;
```

Below is yet another way

```
import React from "react";
import { getElementName } from "utils/enums";

const ElementPreview = ({ element }) => {
  return <img src={require(`assets/elements/${element}.svg`)} alt={getElementName(element)} />;
};

export default ElementPreview;
```

Comment: Thank you Nithish. I went with Agustin's approach since that was a bit shorter. But your second solution looked similar.